# How to put a loading page while waiting for the long-time processing method completes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Codes in aspx file are as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadimg() {            
    window.location.href = "../OutputHtml/loading.html";
    return true;
}
</script>

<asp:ImageButton title="fetch matrix" ImageUrl="~/Images/matrix.png" ID="btnRouteMatrix" OnClientClick="return loadimg();" runat="server" OnClick="btn_RouteMatrix" />
```

After clicking ImageButton, the corresponding page didn't change at all.  The trick part is when I change the "window.location.href" to "parent.window.location.href", like that:

```
function loadimg() {            
    parent.window.location.href = "../OutputHtml/loading.html";
}
```

the parent page(that is the whole page) changed right away. What's wrong with that. Is there other ways for me to put a loading page in the working frame before the btn_RouteMatrix method completes?

Answer (score 0):

Woah, hold up there bud.

You don't need to load a totally independant page just to show a loading icon.
A suggestion would be to have an image on your page pointing to your loading icon, and hide it.

Then, when you call your method, make the first thing it does to show it, then hide it once the processing is complete.

**Example:**

```
<img id="loader" alt="loader" src="../Images/Loader.gif" style="display:none" />
<button type="button" onclick="runMethod()">Click Me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function runMethod(){
     $("#loader").show();


     // Long running method


     $("#loader").hide();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I think the OP is referring to a server side long running process

Comment: I process will be started by ajax request this is the option, but show/hide should be triggered by request start/complete